# Get a XElement at a given path

Tags: c#, xml

I want to traverse a xml tree until I find the first element whose position matches the path. So if I'm looking for `Foo/Bar/FooBar` I want to get this:

```
<Root>
  <Foo>
    <Bar>
      <FooBar /> <!-- This one -->
    </Bar>
  </Foo>
</Root>
```

However there could be any number of `<FooBar />'s` in my way and I only want the one at this path. I wrote 2 methods to get this:

```
private static XElement ElementByName(XElement parent, string name)
{
  return parent.Elements().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName == name).First();
}

private static XElement ElementAtPath(XElement root, string path)
{
  XElement target = root;
  string[] pathArr = path.Split('/');
  for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length; i ++)
    {
      target = ElementByName(target, pathArr[i]);
    }
  return target;
}
```

Is there a faster / more efficient way I could achieve this?

Comment: There is, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642829/how-to-use-xpath-with-xelement-or-linq) - you need to use `XPath` ;-)

Comment: Using `(XElement)root.XPathSelectElement(path);` doesn't work for me

Comment: Maybe XMLreader and then you stop at the first.

Comment: I removed the [tag:performance] tag because you hadn't provided any benchmarks and sample data and without them no one can actually tell you which approach is or would be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following which utilizes XPath's XPathSelectElement extension method.

**test.xml**

```
<Root>
  <Foo>
      <FooBar>1</FooBar>
    <Bar>
      <FooBar>2</FooBar>
    </Bar>
  </Foo>
</Root>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

...

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
        XElement element = ElementAtPath(document.Root, "Foo/Bar/FooBar");

        Console.WriteLine(element); // Prints <FooBar>2</FooBar>
    }

    private static XElement ElementAtPath(XElement root, string path)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(root));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid path.");
        }

        return root.XPathSelectElement(path);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
private static XElement ElementByName(XElement parent, string name)
{
  // Use FirstOrDefault() or another selector to find the relevant element
  return parent.Descendants(name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Usage:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"<path to file>");
var result = ElementByName(document.Root, "FooBar");
```